# On the syntax of \newcommand

Tags: macros

I have the following very basic question.

Say that I want to create a shortcut with \newcommand, call it `\newcommand{\Bla}{BLA^{bla}}`. Now, if I call it in the text with an additional `^{...}`, e.g., I write `\Bla^{...}` to get the output `BLA^{bla...}`, there is an error.

I see why there is the error, but I still have the following question: how can be this error be avoided by keep on having the shortcut?

PS: Any help or edit is most welcome, since I can hardly find how to give to my problem an actual name (as the title and the tags clearly shows),

Comment: You could probably use a command with an optiona argument, for example as in: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Bla}[1][]{BLA^{bla #1}}
\begin{document}
$\Bla, \Bla[...], BLA^{bla...}$
\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know how to use options.

Comment: also it depends what you want `\Bla^{zz}` to be, possible non-error things are `BLA^{blazz}` or `BLA^{bla}{}^{zz}` or `{BLA^{bla}}^{zz}`  this last one would have the zz higher superscripting the already superscripted expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task can be solved classically using TeX primitives:

```
\def\Bla{\futurelet\next\Blax}
\def\Blax{\ifx^\next\afterfi{\Blay}\else\afterfi{\Blay^{}}\fi}
\def\Blay^#1{BLA^{bla#1}}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

%test:
$\Bla, \Bla^2$
```

The `\Bla` macro uses supporting macros `\Blax` and `\Blay`. The second one defines the main behavior of the macro, i.e. BLA is printed following by `^{bla}` or `^{bla<text>}`. We suppose that `\Bla` is used in math. mode.
The `\futurelet\next\Blax` saves the next token to `\next` and runs `\Blax`. The `\Blax` runs `\Blay` if `\next` is `^` and it runs `\Blay^{}` in other cases.

```
% suppose \Bla z:
\next is z
\Blay^{} expands to BLA^{bla} followed by z
% suppose \Bla^z:
\next is ^
\Blay^{z} expands to BLA^{blaz}.
```

Comment: Wow. This is actually supercool! May I ask you some explanation behind the code (i.e., how the x and y enter the picture) for those who could stumble upon this question/answer and want to undestand what is going on?

Comment: I supposed that TeX primitives are generally known. But I will try to add more explanation. Please, wait a while.

Comment: Really much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

With `\NewDocumentCommand` you can use so called embellishments. These are optional arguments started by a specific token, like so:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%\usepackage{xparse} % no longer needed with newer LaTeX versions
\NewDocumentCommand \bla { E{^}{{}} }{Bla^{bla#1}}

\begin{document}
$\bla$ and $\bla^{2}$.
\end{document}
```

The syntax of the `E` type argument is a bit weird on first look: `E{<list of tokens>}{<list of defaults>}`. That's why I use `E{^}{{}}` (`^` will be the token, and the default belonging to `^` will be empty). Using two embellishments, you'd do something like `E{^_}{{}{abc}}`, that would create two arguments, one started by `^` defaulting to an empty value, and one started by `_` defaulting to `abc`.

Comment: This seems rather cool (even if for unfathomable reasons, it does not compile)

Comment: @Kolmin maybe your version of LaTeX is not the latest, in that case uncomment the `\usepackage{xparse}` and it should work.

Comment: I actually did it and that still didn't work. I found it puzzling.

Comment: Which version of LaTeX are you using? Maybe yours is too old and doesn't yet contain the `E` type in `xparse`.

Comment: That has to be the problem.